# How can I import a crash report in xcode6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The crash report used to be in Organizer. Too bad from me! Apple likes to move things around and I can no longer can find it in Xcode 6!

Can somebody share where it is found?

Answer (score 4):

OK, bobnoble was right, it's there in the windows/devices.
However, there is no longer an import option.

In case someone else is looking for this feature, here is how:
After opening the devices, view log, select all logs, and drag crash file from Finder into tree list, it will import itself and re-symbol itself!

Comment: Worked for me.  Also, make sure the file extension is ".crash".

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6, go to Window -> Devices.

Comment: OK, bobnoble was right, it's there in the windows/devices. However, there is no longer an import option.

In case someone else is looking for this feature, here is how: After opening the devices, view log, select all logs, and drag crash file from Finder into tree list, it will import itself and re-symbol itself!

But sorry I am new here and unable to vote up.